# Using collection_select() to filter events on fullCalendar()

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

On my page I am using a drop down box to filter which events are shown on my `fullCalendar()`. My code is as follows:

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready - >
  $("#msCalendar").fullCalendar({
    header: left: "prev today"
    center: "title"
    right: "month,basicWeek next"
    editable: true
    events: "marketingSchedule"
    eventRender: (event, element, view) - >
      return ['all', event.quoted_by].indexOf($('#msQuotedBy').val()) >= 0
    eventClick: (event) - >
      setTimeout(- >
        eventClickFunction(event)
      )
  })

$('#msQuotedBy').change - >
  $('#msCalendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents')
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="msQuotedBySearch">
  <b>Filter by Initials: </b>
  <select id="msQuotedBy">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="ZR">ZR</option>
    <option value="TM">TM</option>
    <option value="jh">jh</option>
    <option value="TD">TD</option>
    <option value="LG">LG</option>
    <option value="BCS">BCS</option>
    <option value="DLH">DLH</option>
    <option value="jr">jr</option>
    <option value="CP">CP</option>
    <option value="LR">LR</option>
    <option value="SA">SA</option>
    <option value="TN">TN</option>
    <option value="DB">DB</option>
    <option value="TF">TF</option>
    <option value="dev">dev</option>
    <option value="BK">BK</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

Using these two blocks of code my calendar gets updated correctly. Obviously the HTML should be better as it doesn't update the drop down box dynamically with users from the database.

I have tried this in my **HTML** and it populates the drop down box correctly but it no longer updates the calendar.

```
<span id="msQuotedBy">
  <b>Filter by Initials: </b>
  <%= collection_select(:user, :initials, User.all, :id, :initials) %>
</span>
```

Any ideas on how to filter my calendar by using `collection_select()`, or perhaps a different method?

Comment: `<%= collection_select(:user, :initials, User.all, :id, :initials) %>` we have no idea what HTML this code produces. Have you checked that it creates what you expect? We have to assume it creates something different than your hand-coded version, otherwise it ought to work just the same as before.

Comment: " I'm not sure what it produces either."...you don't need to know rails to know that. You just need to know how to click the "View Source" button in your browser and view the generated HTML.

Comment: One thing just noticed now from your question though....`<span id="msQuotedBy">`. In your hand-coded example, "msQuotedBy" is the id of the _select_, not the _span_. In the JS, `$('#msQuotedBy').val()` tries to read from the HTML element which has the id "msQuotedBy" and get its value. `<span`s do not have values, but `<select`s do. You've screwed it up by moving the ID to another element. IDs are supposed to uniquely identify the element (hence "ID") - moving it around at random is asking for trouble. Make sure your Rails code sets the correct ID on the `<select` when it creates it.

Comment: Since I don't know Rails I can't really advise you. Perhaps if you consult the docs for that function it provides a way to insert hand-coded options into the list. Or perhaps you can manually add an option to your user list before you pass it to the function, I don't know.

Comment: All right, thanks for your help! I'm gonna start deleting some of these comments that are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example (using Rails), there's a problem:

```
<span id="msQuotedBy">
```

In your hand-coded example, "msQuotedBy" is the id of the select, not the span. In the JS, `$('#msQuotedBy').val()` tries to read from the HTML element which has the id "msQuotedBy" and get its value. `<spans` do not have values, but `<selects` do.

You've screwed it up by moving the ID to another element. IDs are supposed to uniquely identify the element (hence "ID") - moving it around at random is asking for trouble.

Make sure your Rails code sets the correct ID on the `<select` when it creates it. From your comment, the correct overall code should be:

```
<span id="msQuotedBySearch">
  <b>Filter by Initials: </b>
  <%= collection_select(:msQuotedBy, :select, User.all, :initials, :initials) %>
</span>
```